# Pathfinding with negative nodes

Tags: java, path, path-finding

I'm building a simple Java app for an RTS game. The level/map is constructed using a 2D array like so...

```
objectsInWorld[3][numberOfObjects]

oIW[0][i] = x position of object i
oIW[1][i] = y position of object i
oIW[2][i] = size of object i
```

Each of the objects in the array can be a certain type. For example, some represent buildings, and some represent units/people. Is there a way to find a path between location *[x1][y1]* and *[x2][y2]*, where the path does not intersect with certain objects in the array (such as a building at *[x3][y3]*)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a really good guide on pathfinding. You may find what you want here.
    http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/index.html

Comment: Thx, I'll look trough it, and get back on you.
I think i've seen this one before tho.